# If the chance of something to occur is 1/5000 does that mean there is a 50% chance of it occuring at 1/2500?

Tags: probability

So if the chance of something to occur is 1/5000 we should expect that every 5000 instances of this event, it should occur on average, does this mean that there is a 50% chance of it occurring at 1/2500?

Comment: We _expect_ one occurrence of the "something" in 5000 trials but that does not mean will will see exactly one "something" in 5000 trials. We might see two "somethings", or three, or none. There is actually about a 37% chance that the "something" does not occur at all in 5000 trials.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this event occurs independantly, randomly, singly and at a constant average rate of once per 5000 time intervals, we can model the event by using a [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) distribution. In that case
$$X\sim Po(0.5)$$
is the distribution of the amount of times this event occurs in $2500$ time intervals. The chance that this event occurs in $2500$ time intervals is then
$$P(X\ge1)=1-P(X=0)=1-\frac{e^{-0.5}\times0.5^0}{0!}\approx 0.3935\lt 0.5$$
So, there is not a $50$% chance of the event occurring in this time interval. There is in fact a roughly $39$% chance of the event occurring.